# Django: Exclude Extra Users

Tags: python, django

Here's my Query,

```
users = User.objects.all() # contains all users

extra_users = Models.objects.filter(user=request.user) # contains few users related to request.user through ManyToMany relationship
```

Hoe can I exclude extra_users from users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 extra_users = Models.objects.filter(user=request.user) 
 users = Users.objects.exclude(pk__in=extra_users)
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine :). Thank You Sir !

Answer (score 0):

`Users.objects.all().exclude(user=request.user)`

Comment: rollinger, code only answers aren't very helpful since they don't explain the solution. Please expand your answer so that it's a little more comprehensive.